# Alternative to .concat() of empty dataframe, now that it is being deprecated?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have two dataframes that can both be empty, and I want to concat them.

Before I could just do :

```
output_df= pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

But now I run into

> FutureWarning: The behavior of DataFrame concatenation with empty or all-NA entries is deprecated. In a future version, this will no longer exclude empty or all-NA columns when determining the result dtypes. To retain the old behavior, exclude the relevant entries before the concat operation.

An easy fix would be:

```
if not df1.empty and not df2.empty:
    result_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
elif not df1.empty:
    result_df = df1.copy()
elif not df2.empty:
    result_df = df2.copy()
else:
    result_df = pd.DataFrame()
```

But that seems pretty ugly. Does anyone have a better solution ?

FYI: this appeared after pandas released [v2.1.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.1.0.html#deprecations)

Comment: You may still use `pd.concat` if you are fine with the new behaviour. The only difference is that the type of the dataframe will change, but it will still concatenate the dataframes. Will that be an issue to you?

Comment: @FrankVel What will be the new type ? Also, is it bad to remove Future warnings with `warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)` ?

Comment: I don't know how the new type will be. You genreally shouldn't hide warnings, since they don't affect your code. However, if you're concerned about noisy output, you can [temporarily suppress warnings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings) so you just ignore that particular function (and not all other warnings).

Comment: It's giving me this message if there is a valid index but an empty column, so it is not a just for empty dataframe. What was the old behaviour of the type of empty column and what is the new behaviour. Does anyone care? I'd be perfectly happy for this message to disappear.

Comment: So to reduce chattiness it seems one should: filter the warning, then later upgrade pandas to the non-warning state, then remove the warning filter? :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To be precise, [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) is not deprecated (and won't be IMHO) but I can trigger [*this*](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/a0babcb2c63dd721ea47e75f6229c5fe727b2395/pandas/core/internals/concat.py#L492) `FutureWarning` in [`2.1.1`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/releases/tag/v2.1.1) with the following example, while `df2` being an empty DataFrame with a different [`dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html) than `df1` :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [.1, .2, .3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A"], dtype="object")

out = pd.concat([df1, df2]) ; print(out)

     A
0  0.1
1  0.2
2  0.3
```

As a solution in your case, you can try something like you did :

```
out = (df1.copy() if df2.empty else df2.copy() if df1.empty
       else pd.concat([df1, df2]) # if both DataFrames non empty
      )
```

Or maybe even this one? :

```
out = pd.concat([df1.astype(df2.dtypes), df2.astype(df1.dtypes)])
```

Comment: If those are two code options, I'd make it two code blocks. It reads like one code snippet at present. (Also, how will they behave if they have two non-empty data frames with differing signatures?)

Comment: I updated the answer to address the first part of your comment. And regarding your question, if both dataframes have different signatures (*dtypes, shapes, ...*), this is a classical concatenation and thus, will be handled by both solutions.

Comment: Thank you for such a precise answer @Timeless :)

Answer (score 7):

I found this solution based on @Timeless answer the most "non-ugly" for me.

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [3]: df = pd.concat([
   ...:     df if not df.empty else None,
   ...:     pd.DataFrame([{'A': 1.1, 'B': 2.2}])
   ...: ])

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
     A    B
0  1.1  2.2
```

Answer (score 5):

A pretty simple solution to resolve this warning is:

Define a dataframe like this,

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
```

Instead of this,

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
# or df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

Then, you can `concat` on this dataframe with other `dataframe`s you have.

```py
df = pd.concat([df, df_other])
```

It'll work perfectly fine now!

Comment: I don't love this solution as the empty df might already have a structure...

Answer (score 4):

Try this if you know that there might be empty dataframe in the df_list

```py
df_list = [df1, df2, ...]

df = pd.concat([df for df in df_list if not df.empty])
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this more generic solution?:

```
list_of_dfs = [df1, df2, dfx]
# now remove all columns from the dataframes which are empty or have all-NA 
cleaned_list_of_dfs = [df.dropna(axis=1, how='all') for df in list_of_dfs]
output_df = pd.concat(cleaned_list_of_dfs)
```

or with your example in one line:

```
output_df= pd.concat(df.dropna(axis=1, how='all') for df in [df1, df2])
```

That said, you might want to clean those columns out in a more explicit cleaning step and not necessarily during concatenation. Probably a user doesn't expect that some columns disappear during concatenation and that is why they have removed this behavior from future panda.